# Translate dynamic string using AppLocalizations in flutter

Tags: flutter, dynamic, localization

I want to create a drop down menu for gender.

```dart
enum Gender {
  male,
  female,
}
```

```dart
final localization = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;

DropdownButtonFormField(
  hint: Text(localization.gender),
  items: Gender.values
      .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<Gender>(
            value: item,
            // TODO: translate
            child: Text(item.name),
          ))
      .toList(),
),
```

app_fa.arb:

```json
{
  "gender": "جنسیت",
  "male": "مرد",
  "female": "زن"
}
```

Everything works well, just I don't know how should I translate 'male' and 'female' and put them in menu items. I need a method which translates a string using keys in `.arb` file.

I'm using `flutter_localizations` and main language of my app is Persian.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to match you `Gender` enum value with your `Map` key for your Translations:

```dart
enum Gender { male, female }

void main() {
  final Map<String, String> translations = {
    "male": "مرد",
    "female": "زن",
  };

  Gender.values.map((gender) {
    final item = translations
      .entries
      .firstWhere((element) => element.key == gender.name);
    print(item.value);
  }).toList();
}
```

prints out:

```
مرد
زن
```

This is the full example scope with my logic:

[image: Map Dart]

Following your code, you'll need to find the matching key from the available localizations:

```dart
enum Gender { male, female }

final localization = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;

final genders = {
  "male": localization.male,
  "female": localization.female,
};

Gender.values.map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<Gender>(
       value: item,
       child: Text(genders.entries
           .firstWhere((entry) => entry.key == item.name)
           .value))
   .toList());
```

Comment: this is good but if I modify the enum, I should modify `genders` too. Isn't there any way to use a string to get translation from arb file?

Comment: you need to match both keys... if not, there's no way for you to map the enum with your localizations. If not, just use DropdownMenuItem<String> and use a map flike the one I created "genders"

Comment: localization can only give you a value... but the value always change depending the language, that's why you need to create a key for those.

Comment: it's a workaround, and it will lead to a boilerplate